# Magento 2 - some products not showing in frontend - 404 site not found

Tags: magento2, product, frontend, magento2.3.4

I am editing the description of a certain product for hours now and saved alot during this time and it always worked and showed me the updated description in the frontend after reload, but now I suddenly get **404 site not found** in the frontend.

So I tried `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` but it was not helpful.

I also flushed all caches.

I also tried to call the product directly with

`https://www.example.com/catalog/product/view/id/3860`

but I also get 404.

Comment: Some products selected catalog,search??

Comment: "catalog, search" is selected in Visibility, yes.

Comment: You get 404 product error when URL are changed or not?? If yes, please check backend check URL are same or not..

Comment: I don't understand your question. Yes I get 404 error.

Comment: Without 404 products page URL and with 404 products page URL shar me please

Answer (score 0):

you always get 404 when system is unable to define the requested path which means system can't find the URL path

1. check the path
2. clean mangeto cache may be magento is loading from cache

   php bin/magento c:f

if this is not working then

3. clean the browser cache as well

and for design deploy content

```
php bin/magento s:s:d -f en_US en_GB
```

hope this answer helps

Comment: Does not work too. I even tried to call the product directly by using it's ID, `https://www.example.com/catalog/product/view/id/3860` but I also get 404.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. I compared each option of a not working product, with the options of a working product.

I figured out that there is a option "Product at websites" (Produkt auf Webseiten [german]).

There is a checkbox and it was not selected in the not working product, for some unknown reasons. No one has ever changed it as the log proofs, so it must have been changed by magento logic or by a bug.

After this I had to flush the "Page Cache" and now it works again.

---

I think because I enalbed "Single Store Mode" and disabled it again because my design was not loading anymore because of it. But I did the same in another shop and do not experience the same issue there...